# Retrofit JSON Array Parsing

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

cant understand how to parse this json array.

---

[{"id":"154","ontime":"2016-03-15","offtime":"2016-04-14","usluga_id":"2","name":"50mpbs","period":"30","cost":"300"},

{"id":"152","ontime":"2016-03-15","offtime":"2016-04-14","usluga_id":"4","name":"TV60","period":"30","cost":"100"},

{"id":"156","ontime":"2016-03-15","offtime":"2016-04-04","usluga_id":"5","name":"TV120","period":"20","cost":"200"},

{"id":"153","ontime":"2016-03-15","offtime":"2016-03-30","usluga_id":"6","name":"SMS-check","period":"15","cost":"50"}]

---

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")

```
public class UserService {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("ontime")
@Expose
private String ontime;
@SerializedName("offtime")
@Expose
private String offtime;
@SerializedName("usluga_id")
@Expose
private String uslugaId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("period")
@Expose
private String period;
@SerializedName("cost")
@Expose
private String cost;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The ontime
 */
public String getOntime() {
    return ontime;
}

/**
 *
 * @param ontime
 * The ontime
 */
public void setOntime(String ontime) {
    this.ontime = ontime;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The offtime
 */
public String getOfftime() {
    return offtime;
}

/**
 *
 * @param offtime
 * The offtime
 */
public void setOfftime(String offtime) {
    this.offtime = offtime;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The uslugaId
 */
public String getUslugaId() {
    return uslugaId;
}

/**
 *
 * @param uslugaId
 * The usluga_id
 */
public void setUslugaId(String uslugaId) {
    this.uslugaId = uslugaId;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The period
 */
public String getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

/**
 *
 * @param period
 * The period
 */
public void setPeriod(String period) {
    this.period = period;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The cost
 */
public String getCost() {
    return cost;
}

/**
 *
 * @param cost
 * The cost
 */
public void setCost(String cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

---

```
public class ServicesArray {

private List<UserService> services;
public ServicesArray(){};

public List<UserService> getServices() {
    return services;
}

public void setServices(List<UserService> services) {
    this.services = services;
}
```

---

In activity...

public void GetUserServices(){

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://cybergenesis.ru/egor/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<ServicesArray> call = service.getUserServices("egoraa");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ServicesArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServicesArray> call, retrofit2.Response<ServicesArray> response) {
            String[] services = new String[response.body().getServices().size()];
            response.body().getServices().toArray(services);
        Log.d(TAG,"OKKKK");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServicesArray> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG,"ERROR PROFIT");
        }
    });
}
```

**Log:D/MainScreen: ERROR PROFIT**

---

Response is null, what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is a list of users, so instead of making a `ServicesArray` class to parse, you should desirialize it as if it is a list of `User` objects:

```
  Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<User>>(){}.getType();
  List<User> users = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,type);
```

instead of:

```
  List<User> users = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of users. Use this as the return type of the service callback. Array maps to List in retrofit.

```
public class UserList{

private List<User>users;

public UserList(){};

public List<User>getUsers() {
return users;
}

 public void setUsers(List<User>users) {
  this.users= users;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set GSON Converter on all your responses if all of them in json format

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)    
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()))
            .build();
```